# Remove elements stored from a html() method

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove some elements from a block of code I'm storing in a variable from a html() method. Example.

```
<div id="block">
  <div id="temp"><span>dsgdgdgdgdg</span></div>
  <ul>
    <li>dsfdsfsdfds</li>
    <li>dsfdsfsdfds</li>
    <li>dsfdsfsdfds</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

JS CODE

```
    var html = $('#block').html();
    html.remove('#temp');
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove the `temp` element from the page, or just from the html string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a string you can no longer call jQuery methods on it. You would have to recreate the jQuery object from the string, but rather than do that you can just create a copy of the jQuery object to begin with, remove the div, and then get the html string:

```
var $block = $('#block').clone();
$('#temp', $block).remove();
var html = $block.html();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78whr/)

Comment: Thanks Paulpro thats exactly what I'm after. Is there a way to remove multiple elements in one go. right now I'm removing element with id=temp. But I want to remove other child elements. Example id="temp2"

Comment: You're welcome! Use a comma to separate multiple selectors in one selector string: `'#temp, #temp2'`. That applies anywhere you use a jQuery selector :)

Comment: Ah I thought I tried that. Anyway I tried it again and it worked. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should turn it around:

```
$('#block #temp').remove();
```

This will remove every element with `id = "temp"` that is a descendant of an element with `id = "block"`

You are trying to search through the HTML, but html is just a string.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues to overcome in your code.

The first is that `remove(selector)` is a way to remove items from a collection that match a selector, you don't want to do this you want to remove a child element.

The second is that your `html` variable is a string containing the html, not a jQuery object.

Here is a method to overcome both...

```
var html = $('#block');

// Some other code...

$('#temp', html).remove();
```

Update... the above example removes the element from the original block, to operate over the string you need to bring it back into a jQuery object - here is an example...

```
var html = $('#block').html();

var test = $('<div />').html(html); // get string into a jQuery object
$('#temp', test).remove(); // remove the temp element
html = test.html(); // get the update html string

alert(html);
```

Comment: I have tried this but when I append the html again its still showing the #temp element.

Comment: Sorry Steve I had to give the vote to Paulpro as he was the first one to come up with what I was looking for. Even though right after that you updated your code to work the way I need it. Sorry again but thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries - he definitely got in first, so he'll get an up-vote from me too.